# Querying from Oracle Clob column which contains MongoDB doc

Tags: mongodb, oracle, parsing, json-table

Our we use mongodb to store application data. And Oracle DBMS for datawarehousing. Our data engineer synced transaction data from mongo to oracle, where he lumped whole transaction sequenct in 1 column as clob.
Now I want to extract necessary data such as userid, transaction amount, status etc from said column.

Here is an example doc:

```json
{ "\_id" : ObjectId("652e4eea5df2d790"), "processId" : ObjectId("652e4e792883e824c0"), "sessionId" : ObjectId("652e403bc3c52bb66"), "userId" : ObjectId("61976934afe29f99df6c2"), "phoneNumber" : "99081825", "apiName" : "https://dpp-api.toki.mn/teller/v1/teller/transactions/lendP2M", "actionType" : "DPP", "status" : "SUCCESS", "request" : { "accountId" : "61976934afedf6c2", "amount" : 1500, "targetAccountIdentifier" : "63748ecb5956cce", "requestId" : "652e4ee93eb24c2", "type" : "P2M", "description" : "Payment for parking" }, "response" : { "transNumber" : "11093424", "response" : "SUCCESS" }, "error" : null, "createdAt" : ISODate("2023-10-17T14:37:54.293+05:30"), "expiresAt" : ISODate("2023-11-14T08:10:17.853+05:30"), "\__v" : 0 }
```

I was using `json_table()` function to parse it to some avail, but MongoDB doc is not exactly json. For starters, fields can take Object as value like `userid: Objectid("userid")` which will result in error from json_table. For now I am replacing `"Objectid("` and `")"`  with empty string, there is also true/false flag which don't have quotation and resulting in whole query to return null result.

Q: Is there a better way to handle text in MongoDb document format in Oracle itself without resorting to python/r etc.

P.S: I am only a user with only select priviliges. So I can't define functions, procedures. I can only select from blah blah.

Comment: Your process moving data from MongODB to ORACL E